# Oracle DB to Oracle DB Connection Connection forward

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, dblink

I have a question regarding oracle DB's. Consider we have an Oracle Database A and it has a DR named B.
For patching and other changes, some times DB A/B has a downtime.
Few of our clients are correcting to A and few of them are connecting to database B respectively.
Is there a way to have a single connection like an LB, where it can redirect the connection accordingly so that connection from Clients will just point to a single connection and from backend, DBA can redirect to whichever DB using same Connection details. Is there a detailed link for such implementation?

Comment: Am not asking about DB links.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can include multiple addresses for failover, for a given entry in your tnsnames file See "Multiple Descriptions in tnsnames.ora" in the *Database Net Services Reference*   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-7F967CE5-5498-427C-9390-4A5C6767ADAA